# Syntax error in sh file but command working on bash

Tags: bash, syntax-error, sh

I am newbie with bash so it must be a little thing (I hope) but can not find the problem's source.

I have a mysql database table called "url" full of urls. That I want is take all the list and visit them with wget. Nothing more.

I had this command, and launching directly in bash works:

```
while read dbname; do dbarray+=("$dbname"); done < <(mysql -u MYUSER -pMYPASSWD, -e 'select url from mydb.url where borrado="n" and status=200 and id_idioma = 1 order by id_url asc' -B -N -s --skip-column-names) && for dbname in `echo ${dbarray[*]}`; do wget --no-check-certificate $dbname -O /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1; done && unset dbarray
```

But if I put it into a sh file and execute it throw a error (please note that line 3 is the command):

`` line 3: Syntax error near unexpected token `<' ``

I tried to avoid <() pipe method to "traditional" pipe but as same way, it works executing directly in bash as command but not in .sh file

```
 mysql -u MYUSER -pMYPASSWD -e 'select url from mydb.url where borrado="n" and status=200 and id_idioma = 1 order by id_url asc' -B -N -s --skip-column-names | while read dbname; do dbarray+=("$dbname"); done && for dbname in `echo ${dbarray[*]}`; do wget --no-check-certificate $dbname -O /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1; done && unset dbarray
```

In this case not throw error, but it takes 1 second to finnish and do nothing, not visit any link..

Tried executing *./myfile.sh* and *sh myfile.sh*, with no luck..

Could you help me to make it work from a sh file or make me understand where is the problem?

Please note it have 3 commands concatenated with &&: 1 take all urls and create a var with them, 2 loop var and wget each iteration, 3 delete var.
I think is the correct way but maybe I'm wrong. Obviously must wait to finnish 1 to do 2, and to finnish 2 to do 3, is that I wanted. Is it the correct aproximation as you point of view?

Cheers

Comment: Why not just have the script file run with bash (start it with `#!/bin/bash`)?

Comment: Sorry I forget to put it or seems to me reiterative, but yes these line is already the start of sh file, line 1 is #!/bin/bash and line 3 the problematic line, nothing more in file

Comment: @svcd : Please don't post your whole script in a single line. It is difficult to read. As for your question: POSIX shell does not support process substitution.

Comment: @user1934428 I tried to separare at sh file but error persists in same place, and was trying design in one-command way and directly in shell prompt to be executed by cron, this is the reason of the one-line, It worked and then I tried to make a sh file with the command thinking is better than all this command direclty.. Will edit the question when I double check my human friendly version is not failing or throwing another error. Will read about process substitution, thank you

Comment: If you are getting rid of process substitution in order to work with  `sh`, you are going to have to get rid of the array, too.

Comment: thanks @chepner for advice and edit the code I was wonderind how to do it need to read again the howto :)

Comment: @svcd : IMHO, working without arrays is tedious. Do you really **have** to use POSIX? I would try to stick with bash or ksh or zsh (my personal preference being the latter), instead of using a language where it is a pain to do serious development. Just my opinion - not everyone here will agree.

Comment: @user1934428 I need to run it with a cron in a linux server, must be POSIX? well only will be executed there, will not be in a large development, and honestly I dont feel I have the knowledge to response you at your level, but you point some things that I want to see more deep. With William's tips it is working, not using array now but do the wget in first while. I'm not sure if its POSIX approach.. but love to keep learning

Comment: @user1934428 Now I undestand my mistake I was acting like sh and bash command are the same, I understand now the difference, learned about process substitution and why my first command is not POSIX compliant and clearly bash, not sh. And if its runned by bash command instead sh command, works like a charm. Noob things... There was another design errors as William pointed. Thank you sir

Comment: @svcd : IMHO, the whole POSIX sh worship isn't doing much good. People usually argue that in favour of compatibility, we should stick with Posix shell, just in case you are on a network where one of the nodes has no other shell installed than sh. Perhaps this can be true in some embedded environments, where the software is stripped down to the bare necessity, but unless you have such platforms in mind, I don't think you will find a host where you don't have bash and zsh available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pipe, variables are being set in a subshell.  In other words:

```
echo foo | while read a; do var="$a"; done
echo "$var"
```

will print an empty line because `var` goes away when the subshell exits.  One way to get around that is to do:

```
echo foo | { 
    while read a; do var="$a"; done
    echo "$var"
}
```

or:

```
while read a; do var="$a"; done << EOF
$(echo foo)
EOF
echo "$var"
```

In other words, you might try:

```
mysql ... \
| { 
       while read dbname; do dbarray+=("$dbname"); done
       for dbname in "${dbarray[@]}"; do 
           wget ... "$dbname" ...
       done; 
}
```

It is no longer necessary to unset `dbarray`, because it automagically goes away at the end of the block.  It is better to use `"${dbarray[@]}"` than `$(echo ${dbarray[*]})`
and you certainly want double quotes around `"$dbname"` in the `wget` call.

Note that this array seems unnecessary. Just do the `wget` in the `while/read` loop directly instead of assigning to the array.

Comment: so its a scope problem? the sintax error message confused me... And you are totally right its non sense to create the array now, originally was saved for other reasons that no apply now so wget can be done in while loop. Really thank you will rewrite the script with your tips